# Sharp SVN -- Merge not happening even with Merge Complete Status

Tags: c#, svn, merge, sharpsvn

I am trying to do a merge between a working copy and a branch. In my case, we have 3 branches, all 3 of them have the same solution but are parallel branches, so if one changes anything in one branch it needs to be manually updated in the other branches.

For this scenario, I was trying to automate the process and ran into Sharp SVN API. Initially merges were happening fine but later it is showing "Merge Completed" but nothing is actually merged.

Has anybody faced this scenario before ?

I am using the below piece of code for merge:

```
SvnMergeArgs args = new SvnMergeArgs();

//Attaching the events
args.Notify += new EventHandler<SvnNotifyEventArgs>(Merge_Notify);
args.SvnError += new EventHandler<SvnErrorEventArgs>(Merge_Error);
args.Cancel += new EventHandler<SvnCancelEventArgs>(Merge_Cancel);
args.Conflict += new EventHandler<SvnConflictEventArgs>(Merge_Confilct);
args.Depth = SvnDepth.Children;
args.Force = false;
args.IgnoreAncestry = false;
args.RecordOnly = true;

// Calling Sharp Svn Merge Function
client.Connect().Merge(TargetWC, SourceUri, logs.Range(), args);
```

After attaching the cancel event, I found out it goes to cancel event and then at last it says "Merge Completed". But previously it used to do a proper merge!

Comment: Why do you perform a record only merge? That should only set the svn:mergeinfo property and not perform actual merges.

Comment: And .Connect() is not something standard in SharpSvn. Is that some kind of extension method?

Comment: The `.Depth = SvnDepth.Children` could be the reason you don't see a merge here. In 99.9% of the cases you would want to pass depth Infinity.